# get LinkedList instance in java

Tags: java, linked-list, listiterator

I am new in java. I have been trying to do some tests while teaching myself the language. Now I am on a linked list implementation. I chucked the code from test samples online. There are two files, LinkedList and LinkedListIterator. I am alright understanding the implementation. However, I would like to add to methods to the LinkedList class. One method (getString()) will be used to display a concatenation of all the string variables in the linkedlist. The second method getSize() will be used to display the size of the list. I have trouble getting the current instance of the linkedlist so I can iterate and get the strings and size. Can someone please assist? Help will be really appreciated.
The two files are as below:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class LinkedList
{
   //nested class to represent a node
   private class Node
   {
          public Object data;
          public Node next;
   }

   //only instance variable that points to the first node.
   private Node first;

   // Constructs an empty linked list.
   public LinkedList()
   {
      first = null;
   }


   // Returns the first element in the linked list.
   public Object getFirst()
   {
      if (first == null)
       {
         NoSuchElementException ex
             = new NoSuchElementException();
         throw ex;
       }
      else
         return first.data;
   }

   // Removes the first element in the linked list.
   public Object removeFirst()
   {
      if (first == null)
       {
         NoSuchElementException ex = new NoSuchElementException();
         throw ex;
       }
      else
       {
         Object element = first.data;
         first = first.next;  //change the reference since it's removed.
         return element;
       }
   }

   // Adds an element to the front of the linked list.
   public void addFirst(Object element)
   {
      //create a new node
      Node newNode = new Node();
      newNode.data = element;
      newNode.next = first;
      //change the first reference to the new node.
      first = newNode;
   }

   // Returns an iterator for iterating through this list.
   public ListIterator listIterator()
   {
      return new LinkedListIterator();
   }


   public String toString(){

      }

      public int getSize(){
           return this.size();
      }

   //nested class to define its iterator
   private class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator
   {
      private Node position; //current position
      private Node previous; //it is used for remove() method

      // Constructs an iterator that points to the front
      // of the linked list.

      public LinkedListIterator()
      {
         position = null;
         previous = null;
      }

     // Tests if there is an element after the iterator position.
     public boolean hasNext()
      {
         if (position == null) //not traversed yet
          {
             if (first != null)
                return true;
             else
                return false;
          }
         else
           {
              if (position.next != null)
                 return true;
              else
                 return false;
           }
      }

      // Moves the iterator past the next element, and returns
      // the traversed element's data.
      public Object next()
      {
         if (!hasNext())
          {
           NoSuchElementException ex = new NoSuchElementException();
           throw ex;
          }
         else
          {
            previous = position; // Remember for remove

            if (position == null)
               position = first;
            else
               position = position.next;

            return position.data;
          }
      }

      // Adds an element before the iterator position
      // and moves the iterator past the inserted element.
      public void add(Object element)
      {
         if (position == null) //never traversed yet
         {
            addFirst(element);
            position = first;
         }
         else
         {
            //making a new node to add
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.data = element;
            newNode.next = position.next;
            //change the link to insert the new node
            position.next = newNode;
            //move the position forward to the new node
            position = newNode;
         }
         //this means that we cannot call remove() right after add()
         previous = position;
      }

      // Removes the last traversed element. This method may
      // only be called after a call to the next() method.
      public void remove()
      {
         if (previous == position)  //not after next() is called
          {
            IllegalStateException ex = new IllegalStateException();
            throw ex;
          }
         else
          {
           if (position == first)
            {
              removeFirst();
            }
           else
            {
              previous.next = position.next; //removing
            }
           //stepping back
           //this also means that remove() cannot be called twice in a row.
           position = previous;
      }
      }

      // Sets the last traversed element to a different value.
      public void set(Object element)
      {
         if (position == null)
          {
            NoSuchElementException ex = new NoSuchElementException();
            throw ex;
          }
         else
          position.data = element;
      }

   } //end of LinkedListIterator class
}
```

LinkedListIterator class:

```
public interface ListIterator
{
   //Move Moves the iterator past the next element.
   Object next();

   // Tests if there is an element after the iterator position.
   boolean hasNext();

   // Adds an element before the iterator position
   // and moves the iterator past the inserted element.
   void add(Object element);


   // Removes the last traversed element. This method may
   // only be called after a call to the next() method.
   void remove();

   // Sets the last traversed element to a different value.
   void set(Object element);
}
```

Error when I try the implmentation of getSize():

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at assignment10.LinkedList.size(LinkedList.java:84)
    at assignment10.LinkedList.size(LinkedList.java:84)
    at assignment10.LinkedList.size(LinkedList.java:84)
    at assignment10.LinkedList.size(LinkedList.java:84)
```

Comment: What have you tried? The methods are empty. The current instance can be referenced by the keyword ``this``. But I don't think that's the problem here. Use the iterator to get the values one by one.

Comment: You can have `int size` as your class member in `LinkedList` and then you can increase or decrease it in `add` or `remove` methods respectively. 

For string representation you have to create an iterator and iterate over all nodes to format nodes.

Please refer Java's LinkedList for better implementation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: Why don't you simply extend the existing LinkedList? It already has size() method so you could just wrap it with your getSize() and also if you just use the Strings inside you may easyly override toString() method

Answer (score 0):

The `getSize()` could be

```
public int getSize(){
    int size = 0;
    ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();
        size++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

But it is not efficient to iterate over list each time to knowe it's size. The better solution is to store size as class variable and increase or decrease in methods modifying list.

The idea of `toString()` method is the same, iterate over the list and append each item to the result string

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ListIterator iterator = listIterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(String.valueOf(iterator.next())).append(",");
    }

    return sb.toString;
}
```